# Как преобразовать массив в нужный мне обьект?

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, объекты

Есть такой массив
[image: массив]

как мне его преобразовать в такой массив с обьектами

```
[{
0:{login: "Проверочный опрос"},
1:{login: "Первый опрос"},
2:{login: "Все типы ответов"}
}]
```

Comment: `{login: ["Проверочный опрос", "Первый опрос", "Все типы ответов"]}`. Сделайте вот так

Comment: @ArchDemon как?

Comment: Хоспади. `var a = ["Проверочный опрос", "Первый опрос", "Все типы ответов"]; var b = {login: a};`

Comment: @ArchDemon это ладно, как мне преобразовать в такой массив с обьектами?)
[{
0:{login: "Проверочный опрос"},
1:{login: "Первый опрос"},
2:{login: "Все типы ответов"}
}]

Comment: @ArchDemon я делаю

for(var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++)
this.dataarray = [{login: this.data[i]}]

а он сохраняет только последний вариант в списке пройденного в цикле
как мне сохранять все?

Comment: Вам голова нужна чтобы в неё есть? Зачем вы массив перезаписываете? `this.dataarray[i] = {login: this.data[i]};`

Comment: @ArchDemon а что бы был вот аналогичный массив?

[{
0:{login: "Проверочный опрос"},
1:{login: "Первый опрос"},
2:{login: "Все типы ответов"}
}]


как Вы говорите получается обьект 

{
0:{login: "Проверочный опрос"}
1:{login: "Первый опрос"}
2:{login: "Все типы ответов"}
}

Comment: А что по вашему должны означать `[]` в начале и конце объекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const array = ['Проверочный опрос', 'Первый опрос', 'Все типы ответов'];

const transformed = array.reduce((accumulator, value) => {
    accumulator.push({
        login: value
    });

    return accumulator;
}, []);
```

Comment: спасибо, очень помог)